# search and change field value in query result in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Sensor and a query from this model:

```
@sensors = Sensor.where(device_id: 4)
```

Output is:

```
Id  seq_num temp
5   1       40
6   2       41
7   3       45
```

First: I want to search this query result for example locate (find) for seq_num = 2

```
(@sensors.find(seq_num = 2))
```

Second: after find a record change temp value and save to database. It is possible that all of record changed.
How can do first and second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *seq_num* value is unique for all sensors, then you can find a sensor in *@sensors* list by its *seq_num* value using this code:

```
sensor = @sensors.detect { |s| s.seq_num == 2 }
```

*detect* method returns the first found element or nil in nothing was found.

To save all the sensors after updating their *temp* value you can use this code:

```
@sensors.each { |s| s.save }
```

or

```
@sensors.each(&:save)
```

Only those sensors that have temp value changed will be saved.

Comment: after find sensor by detect method. can i change the temp value: sensor.temp = 40 and @sensors.each { |s| s.save }. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
# First
@sensors = Sensor.where(device_id: 4, seq_num: 2)


# Second
Sensor.update_all({:temp => 1}, {device_id: 4, seq_num: 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit unclear.  You want to get a list of all sensors, and then only get the one with seq_num 2.  Do you still need the rest of the data in @sensors? Then you want to change the value in the one you found and save it?   Also do you need to work with the device, since asssuming sensor belongs to device you can query through the Device association.

if you need all sensors in @sensors.  you can do this.

```
@sensors = Sensor.where(device_id: 4)
@sensor = @sensors.find { |sensor| sensor.seq_num == 2 }
```

if you only need the one sensor you can do

```
@senser =  Sensor.where(device_id: 4, seq_num: 2)
```

as for changing the data and saving it ,

```
@sensor.temp = new_temp
@sensor.save
```

Comment: I need all records(3)  in query result and changed all of them. then sensors = Sensor.where(device_id: 4) and sensor = sensors.find { |sensor| sensor.seq_num == 2 }  for find seq_num in result and after find that i want to change temp value from that record and save it. my target is to run one query to database instead of 3 query. is that correct?